# How do I plot points on a sphere using spherical coordinates?

Tags: plotting

Currently, I have a matrix containing a list of spherical coordinates. Column 1 is r; r=1 for all points. Column 2 is theta and column 3 is phi. Each row is an ordered triple (r,theta,phi). Is there a function that I can get to operate on this matrix and plot these points on a sphere of radius 1? Thank you!

-Chase

Comment: Transform the coordinates to Cartesian form, then use `ListPointPlot3D`.

Comment: Could you share your points?

Comment: @MarkMcClure My points are constantly changing as they're based upon roots of different polynomials. One example would be (1, pi/2, pi/4).

Comment: @Szabolcs I think I'll combine your command with George's command. Will ListPointPlot3D apply to a matrix of triples?

Comment: @ChaseYetter `ListPointPlot3D` can accept a matrix but that is probably not what you want: it will interpret each row as a separate sequence of points, and give them a different color. You can use `Flatten[matrix, 1]` to turn it into a list of points.

Comment: `ListPointPlot3D` works with the matrix just fine - use instead of `Graphics3D[Point[..]]` if you want the labeled axes on the figure. ( and you likely needyto specify `BoxRatios` to make it look right )

Answer (score 7):

```
 CoordinateTransformData[ "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping", #]&/@ datalist
```

Example:

```
 Graphics3D@{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .95], 
    Point[CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
           "Mapping", #] & /@ 
          Table[ { 1, RandomReal[{0, Pi}], RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}]}, {2000}]]}
```

[image]

It may also be useful to see how you can roll your own:

```
 sp[{r_, theta_, phi_}] := 
      r {Cos[phi] Cos[theta], Cos[phi] Sin[theta], Sin[phi]};
 Graphics3D@{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .95],
 Point[ sp /@ Table[ { 1, RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], RandomReal[{-Pi/2, Pi/2}]}, {2000}]]}
```

> (*same graphic*)

note here I use a different convention on the ordering of the spherical coordinates and and the range of theta.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform all your data points to xyz and plot them.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{1, theta, phi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10.}, {theta, 0, Pi, 
 Pi/10.}], 1]; (*your set of data*)

rtox[sphdata_] := sphdata /. {r_, theta_, phi_} -> CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, theta, phi}]
(*to change your table to cartesian from spherical*)

ListPointPlot3D[rtox[data], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

And your are done.