# Spinning top: how to plot position on a sphere?

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am modelling a spinning top on a sphere and I want to obtain plots such as these

[image]

I have solved the equations of motion

```
B = 1;
a = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{p'[t] == (B - a*Cos[th[t]])/(Sin[th[t]]^2), 
th''[t] == (p'[t]*(p'[t]*Cos[th[t]] - a) + 1)*Sin[th[t]], 
th[0] == 1, p[0] == 0, th'[0] == 0}, {p, p', th, th'}, {t, 0, 10} ]
```

Then to plot the points I evaluate

```
a = Flatten[Table[th[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]]
b = Flatten[Table[p[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]]
res = Transpose[{Table[1, {t, 0, 10}], a, b
}] (*I want all points on a unit sphere*)
```

Then following what is [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55132/how-do-i-plot-points-on-a-sphere-using-spherical-coordinates?rq=1) I do

```
Graphics3D@{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
Point[CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
  "Mapping", #] & /@ res]}
```

But I get back all sorts of errors as below

[image]

Why so? It looks like this is because my angles phi get quite large as I got around the sphere (n rotations would be 2nPi).

The outputs of NDSolve are the following:

[image]

I think the issue can be solved if all the coordinates theta and phi can be mapped into the range allowed by the coordinate transformation. Mathematica seems to require phi between -pi and pi. So theta should be between 0 and pi. How do I do this? (Very new to mathematica)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have already identified, the problem with `CoordinateTransformData[
 "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping", {r, θ, ϕ}]` is that it wants to treat spherical coordinates as invertible map. Thus, it wants the second argument to lie in the interval $[0,\pi]$ and the third argument to lie in the interval $[-\pi ,\pi]$. You can achieve this by using `Mod`as follows:

```
res1 = res;
res1[[All, 2]] = Mod[res1[[All, 2]], Pi];
res1[[All, 3]] = Mod[res1[[All, 3]], 2 Pi, -Pi];
```

Now, the plot

```
Graphics3D[{
 Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
 Point[CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping", #] & /@ res1]
 }]
```

should work.

Answer (score 5):

There are some problems with `CoordinateTransform` and `CoordinateTransformData` that can be avoided by simply not using these functions.  Here's the problem:  say we want start the top spinning at $\theta=0$.  Try putting the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ coordinates of $(1,0,1)$ into `CoordinateTransform`

```
CoordinateTransform["Spherical"->"Cartesian", {1,0,1} ]
```

and it gives an error because the transformation is not defined at $\theta=0$.  Also, the `Mod` function is not exactly right for the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ coordinates of $(1,1,\pi)$ because

```
Mod[π, 2 π, -π]
```

gives $-\pi$, which is also an undefined value of the transformation.  Try it with

```
CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
    {1, 1, Mod[π, 2 π, -π]}]
```

to see the error.  Of course you may never see these error messages, but you could.

One way to avoid these problems is to not use the `CoordinateTransform` function at all.  Consider the actual $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of your trajectory:

```
xyz = Table[{Cos[p[t]] Sin[th[t]],
     Sin[p[t]] Sin[th[t]],
     Cos[th[t]]} /. First[sol],
   {t, 0, 10, 1/10}];
```

We can plot these coordinates like this:

```
Graphics3D[{Green, Point[First[xyz]],
  Thick, Red, Line[xyz],
  Black, Point[Last[xyz]],
  Arrow[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}],
  Blue, Opacity[1/5], Sphere[]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

The arrow in the plot is so we can see which way is up.

The advantage of using the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates is that we do not have to worry about those what happens when $\theta$ and/or $\phi$ are "out of range".